# Find a probability

Tags: probability

Total number of outcome **win**,**loss** and **draw**

If the probability of scoring a hit is 0.3, army A has 2 units, and army B has 1 unit, then A has a 0.86839 chance of winning, B has a 0.09213 chance of winning and there is a 0.03948 chance of a draw.

How they calculated actual favorable outcome ? I only know about the probability formula :

```
outcome = number of favorable outcome / total number of favorable outcomes.
```

I have been stuck on this problem for 3 hours. Now looking for some one to help me get out from this question.

Comment: I guess this depends on how the "rules" of the game are defined. Do the two armies fire at the same time, or by taking turns?

Comment: Yes it's turn by turn and game over when one of armies does not have any more units.

Comment: Okay. How would you go about calculating, for example, what is the probability that army A wins? Do you have any idea?

Comment: 1)Total outcome is 3(Win,loss and draw) so probability each one is 0.3 and  multiply A 2 unit with 0.33  unlikely it's wrong .

Comment: http://www.spoj.com/problems/BYU15W_4/ Here it's actual source link it might help.

Answer (score 2):

I made a flow chart of the game:

[image]

Perhaps it gives you an idea on how to calculate the probabilities. Markov chain is also a key word here.
I also made a visualization of the Markov chain:

[image]

In the picture, the states with A's and B's are written so that A2B1 corresponds to the state where A has two units and B has one unit.

Now, let's attack the question of "What is the probability that, starting from node $A2B1$, we will (after some amount of moves) end up in node $A2B0$?". Let's denote this with probability $p_{A2B1}$.

From the node $A2B1$ it is possible to either stay in the node, or to move to $A2B0$. Therefore,
$$
p_{A2B1} = 0.343 p_{A2B1} + 0.357 \Rightarrow p_{A2B1} \approx 0.54338
$$
This was one case where A would win and this served as a warm up for the next cases.

Next, let's answer the question "What is the probability that, starting from node $A2B1$, we would (after some amount of rounds) end up in node $A1B0$". Let's denote this with $q_{A2B1}$. We also need the similar probability, starting from $A1B1$, which is $q_{A1B1}$. Interpreting the picture, we get
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
q_{A2B1} &= 0.153 + 0.343q_{A2B1} + 0.147q_{A1B1} \\
q_{A1B1} &= 0.21 + 0.49 q_{A1B1}
\end{array}
\right.
\Rightarrow 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
q_{A2B1} &\approx 0.325 \\
q_{A1B1} &\approx 0.41176
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Therefore, the probability that A wins is $0.54338 + 0.325 = 0.86838$. (Answer to the first question and agreeing with the given result).

Let's then mark the probability that we end up in the node $A0B1$, starting from the node $A2B1$. Let's mark this with probability $b_{A2B1}$. The similar probability, starting from node $A1B1$, is $b_{A1B1}$. We end up with equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
b_{A2B1} &= 0.343b_{A2B1} + 0.147 b_{A1B1}\\
b_{A1B1} &= 0.49b_{A1B1} + 0.21
\end{array}
\right.
\Rightarrow 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
b_{A2B1} &\approx 0.09213 \\
b_{A1B1} &\approx 0.41176
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Therefore, the probability that B wins is $0.09213$. The remaining probability of a draw is $1-0.09213 - 0.86838 = 0.03949$.

Comment: As you stated both turn of A2 and A1 in single step I think it should be turn by turn so value of A2 team become A1 if it's hit by B team. Then next turn  goes for team B.

Comment: In the problem definition page, it says: "Each turn, every unit in both armies either scores a hit or a miss."
I interpret it so that the teams "fire" at the same time.

Comment: Yes agreed ! What would a probability if both user miss target that leads to infinite part ? What you think ?

Comment: Do you mean: What is the probability that the game will go on forever?
What do you think (by interpreting the diagram)?